# How to get a Microsoft Azure Authorization Token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

The Microsoft Azure [Cost Management Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) site offers an interactive panel to test out its REST APIs on the browser. It all works just fine, however I can't figure out how the website retrieves the prepopulated Authorization bearer token to allow me to replicate the call on my computer. Or more so - what do I need to do to retrieve this token?

[image]

**What I have attempted**:

I have been recommended to register a new app and use its credentials to generate a new token, however that token **still** appears to give me an error when using it in the request above (I tried to copy the token from the above example and the request works when I use **it**, so I know the problem is 100% on my token generation approach). How I got my token:

Retrieving the token endpoint url:

[image]

Using it along with the other credentials in Postman to retrieve the token:

[image]

Then using the resultant bearer token to create a new request (like the example in the browser) which yields the ERROR below (this does work if I copy the token from the example...):

[image]

Adding the body and header content for reference:

[image]
[image]

**More attempts**:

Based on @Heidi Tran suggestion, I have created a `user_impersonation` API permission, but unfortunately that did not change the result:

[image]

Based on @RithwikBojja suggestion, I have updated the token retrieval scope property to `https://management.azure.com/.default`. When I generate the token and use it in the original request (1st image), I now get the following error (It is worth noting that the token presented by the browser does work in Postman so the scope is **valid** and the problem is still the token retrieval):

[image]

I have also made sure that I have **read** access as well as **owner** access to my subscription (which yield the same error as above):

[image]

Comment: What language are you wanting to use?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Comment: I tried to use this, but to get a client id and secrets I had to register an app in Azure Active Directory. I did all that and generated a token, however when using it in the request in my example I get the following error: Authentication failed.

Comment: There must be another way of obtaining client id and secrets without registering a new app as the website was able to do retrieve the token before I even had any apps registered...

Comment: No, client ID and secrets are based on the app registration, that's the process.  If you want to login in with a username/password, there is a flow for that as well.  Ask yourself, did you login to run the API?  That's how it got the token.  The second link is the password flow.  If you have MFA setup, you can't use that though.

Comment: Hi @Skin, I have updated my question to show you what I have attempted.

Comment: Hi @Ovidijus Parsiunas, You need to change scope to ```https://management.azure.com/.default``` while generating token

Comment: I now get a `does not have authorization to perform action` error instead, so it may be a step forward but the token is still problematic :/ (I have updated my question to display the error)

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

As @Skin commented you need to create Azure AD  App registration  and use its client Id and secret for generating access token.

Firstly you need to create one Azure AD App registration as below:

[image]

Now in Postman:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f9b47/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type: client_credentials  
client_id: {clientid}  
client_secret: {clientsecret}  
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

Here I got Post `url`(token endpoint url) from below:

[image]

In postman I have got bearer token as below:

[image]

Now use the above access token and run to get the details you want:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/Subid/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2022-10-01
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @RithikBojja, I have followed your instructions step-by-step, but when I use the retrieved token, I still get the "Authentication failed" error. I have updated my question to show you what I did.

Comment: I have tried it multiple times and copied the token correctly from the first letter to the last without any manipulation... I have included the header and body content images in my answer for reference. It is important to note that everything works fine if I replace the token I got from the registered app endpoint with the token in the website, hence the other headers and the body content should be irrelevant.

Comment: No, the issue is still there, what I mean is, if I copy the bearer token from the browser example (1st image) - the post request in Postman works, but if I use the bearer token that I generated from the app endpoint, the post request in Postman does not work, meaning that the problem is 100% the token, which I am trying to find out how to generate in my question...

Comment: I can't seem to edit my comment but what I meant by stating "everything works fine if I replace the token I got from the registered app endpoint with the token in the website" is that when I use the example website token (1st image) it works fine which proves that the header and body content I use in Postman are correct and the token is definitely the problem. Hence my question still stands

Comment: You need to change scope to ```https://management.azure.com/.default``` while generating token

Comment: I have observed you have generated token for graph, you need to change to management in scope, this will clear your error and you will get output as i have got

Comment: I now get a `does not have authorization to perform action` error instead, so it may be a step forward but the token is still problematic :/ (I have updated my question to display the error)

Comment: It means your subscription does not allow you to check these details. You might need to ask your administrator to give you the access to do. Token is not a problem here now, as i am getting my cost details by doing same process. You can check it, it clearly states you need access granted to perform this action. And now no one can help if you still feel the issue is with the token.

Comment: If I don't have permissions to make the request then how does the browser (1st image in the question) provide a valid token for me to use which works in Postman? If I don't have permissions to make the request then surely I should not be able to do it in that example... It makes no sense

Comment: Hence my original question, how does the browser example obtain a valid token?

Comment: You should assign reader role to service principal under your subscription.https://i.imgur.com/ou3YRJI.png

Comment: Hi @RithwikBojja, thankyou for another suggestion! Unfortunately I still get the *does not have authorization to perform action* error... I have updated my answer to show you what I did.

Answer (score 0):

The token was obtained by using Azure Active Directory OAuth2 Flow. Specifically, it's OAuth2 implicit flow with the authorization URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize and "user_impersonation" scope ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#security)). This flow only requires user sign in to get an access token.

You can learn more about this flow here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

However, if you only want the token to test it out quickly on your computer, you can copy it from the Request Review window.

Click on the Copy button on the top left corner of the Request Review window [like example photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHI5m.png) and paste it to a notepad

It would look something like this:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/%7Bscope%7D/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2022-10-01
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL...
Content-type: application/json
```

where

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

Copy everything after `Bearer` , that's your access token. Then you make your http request using `curl` or JavaScript

Comment: How would the `user_impersonation` request look like in POSTMAN, I can't find documentation on if it is a body property and what value it is expected to have.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token explains more details about how to create, register an app, give permission and use `user_impersonation` scope

Comment: I have attempted the described suggestion, but it unfortunately did not solve the problem. I have updated my answer to illustrate what I did.